# Is there a "clean" way to jump out of a "try" block without an exception in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
        try
        {
            if (vm.SubmitAction == "Cancel")
                return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new
                {
                    ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
                 });  <------------------------------------------- xxxx
            _account.ValidateNoDuplicate(vm.Account);
            vm.Account.Modified = DateTime.Now;
            vm.Account.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            _account.AddOrUpdate(vm.Account);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            log(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm); 
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new {
            ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
        });
```

If the user hits the cancel button then I have code ( Marked here with <-- xxxx ) that redirects to an action. This code is the same as the code after the try block. Is there a way that I can make my code exit from the try. The only way I can think of is to trigger an exception and I want a clean jump and not one that uses the exception as it's not an error for a user to click cancel.

Comment: What do you mean by cleanly exit? The code is returning the result of a method call. Unless the method call exceptions, the code will be exited from the try block via return after the execution of the call.

Comment: This code also smells in three other ways: 1) `DateTime.Now` uses local time, you most likely should use UTC since the variable identifies a point in time. i.e. `DateTime.UtcNow`. 2) It should be a service or parameter to the method. It's static and it changes, a bad combination. 3) You have a catch-all. You usually catch specific exceptions locally, and general exceptions in some top level handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the if block condition around:

```
// happens only when not cancelled
if (vm.SubmitAction != "Cancel") 
  try {
     _account.ValidateNoDuplicate(vm.Account);
     vm.Account.Modified = DateTime.Now;
     vm.Account.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
     _account.AddOrUpdate(vm.Account); 
   }
   catch (Exception e) { 
       log(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm); 
   }

// happens always
return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new {
       ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
});
```

Comment: This has a very subtle change in behavior.  In the original code, if `vm` was null, the `NullReferenceException` would be caught.  In this code, it won't be.  Just pointing this out to the OP.  Might want to change the condition to test for null first.

Comment: @Inuyasha: Null reference exceptions should *never* be caught, so this version is *better*. A null reference exception should never be caught because a null reference exception should never be thrown; every null reference exception is a bug you should fix to make it impossible, not an exception you should catch.

Comment: @Eric - in this context I think that you're right, but I think that your statement is too strongly worded if applied more broadly.  Sometimes you may be relying on buggy 3rd party code (where you are powerless to fix the bug), so catching a NRE may be the best of a bad set of options.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to exit a `try` `catch` *manually* (with a `goto` statement) but that's a terrible OO practice and should be avoided.

Encapsulate your `RedirectToAction` logic into a method and call it:

```
try
{
    if (vm.SubmitAction == "Cancel")
        return ShowSummary(vm);
    _account.ValidateNoDuplicate(vm.Account);
    vm.Account.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    vm.Account.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
    _account.AddOrUpdate(vm.Account);
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    log(e); 
    return View("CreateEdit", vm); 
}
return ShowSummary(vm);
```

And the method:

```
private ActionResult ShowSummary(MyViewModel vm)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new
           {
               ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
           });  
}
```

Comment: You *can* exit a try block using a `goto` statement.  See OmarQa's answer.

Comment: Let's just say that I prefer to ignore it. Btw the question mentions the "clean" way. Thank for the update.

Comment: Preferring to ignore it is different than saying it doesn't exist.  It does exist.  It's doing the OP a disservice to tell him something that is false.

Comment: Update my post to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not the best programming keyword but goto do the job

```
try
    {
        if (vm.SubmitAction == "Cancel")
            goto ShowSummary;

        _account.ValidateNoDuplicate(vm.Account);
        vm.Account.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        vm.Account.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        _account.AddOrUpdate(vm.Account);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm);
    }
ShowSummary:
    return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new
        {
            ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
        });
```