# Jump out of "try-catch"?

Tags: language-agnostic, try-catch

Is there a language with a keyword to jump out of `try-catch` block?

For example, there is a walkaround in Ruby:

```
lambda {
    begin
        p 0
        break
        p 1
    rescue
        p 2
    end
}.call
p 3
```

It's also (I believe) possible in Javascript.
But I want a way without anonymous function (to avoid indentation) – like if `break` or `continue` were possible.

I know, that C/C++/C# languages allow [using `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572138/322020).

Do languages with another approach exist?

Comment: I don't think you should want to.    This is a bad idea.  Voting to close.

Comment: Try the return statement.   ;-)

Comment: What is the use case here? Just don't throw an exception and the `try..catch` block won't do anything. Use other constructs like `if..else` or function returns for normal execution control.

Comment: @deceze The use is the same, as use of `continue` and `break` – avoiding `if`-tabulation. Throwing an exception isn't a good style.

Comment: The longer I sit at SO, the more weird question-closings I see. *Not a real question*? Really?!

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof, but maybe I don't want more function names in my namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just throw a known exception which you catch but do nothing with. In c#

```
try {
    if(true)
        throw new GetOutException();
}
catch(GetOutException e) {
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // Do something here    
}
```

Comment: Exception in many languages is a class. And when you raise it, it's a creating of an object, calling a *slow* constructor, etc. Also it could be a spam into logs which you don't actually need.

Comment: @Nakilon: If you don't log it, it won't fill your log. As for the speed, have you actually measured it? Exceptions aren't as slow as many people think. It's wrong to use exceptions for this sort of thing for other reasons though - it makes the program flow a lot harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), you can jump out of any part in the code. For instance, with `call-with-current-continuation` in Scheme. This example from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation#Examples) illustrates the basic concept:

```
(define (f return)
  (return 2)
  3)

(display (f (lambda (x) x))) ; displays 3

(display (call-with-current-continuation f)) ; displays 2
```

In general, a continuation can be used to escape from *any* point in the execution of a procedure (they're *not* limited to `try/catch` blocks), no matter how deeply nested it is - in that regard, it's a more general construct than an `Exception` or a `goto`, as both of those constructs can be implemented in terms of continuations.

At first, continuations are not an easy-to-grasp concept, but with practice they can be very useful, see this [paper](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs491/appcont.pdf) detailing the many possible applications of continuations.

Answer (score 0):

So basically it sounds like you're asking for a `goto` equivalent to skip the execution of particular parts of your code. Something like:

```
foo();
if (!bar) {
    goto end;
}
baz();

end:
print "ended";
```

I won't go into pros and cons of `goto`s, but they're not available in a number of languages for various reasons. You can virtually always formulate your code like below for the same effect though:

```
foo();
if (bar) {
    baz();
}

print "ended";
```

This obviously also works when you're actually using exceptions:

```
try {
    foo();
    if (bar) {
        baz();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    help();
}

print "ended";
```

It has the same effect of skipping the execution of a particular branch of code under certain circumstances and is the standard way to do it. I cannot really imagine a situation where breaking out of a `try..catch` or using an equivalent `goto` would offer any advantage.

Comment: `continue` and `break` for *cycle block* also can be implemented via `if`. But they both exist exactly to make possible to avoid `if` and its indentation. My wish is in the same purpose for *try catch block*.

Comment: `continue` and `break` are specifically for dealing with *iterations* in *looping* control structures. You *could* implement the whole loop using labels and `goto`, then use `if` for `continue` and `break`... But `try..catch` is linear to begin with, it does not loop. Hence I do not really see the comparison. At the core, you simply want to skip the execution of certain blocks of code under certain conditions. That's what `if` is for...

Comment: BTW. Actually `try..catch` can loop. For example, Ruby has very useful `retry` keyword. And I see a lot of Python code with `while True: try ... if (f): break ... except: pass`

Comment: I wouldn't classify that as *"loop"*, it behaves more like `goto`. A loop is a structure which inherently repeats operations a defined number of times. `retry` just jumps back to the beginning of a `try` block in case of an exception; I hope you would never use this to implement a loop. You can abuse almost any language construct for purposes other than what it's meant for, but that doesn't mean you should. In your case you were looking for the functionality of an `if`, so you should use an `if`.

Comment: Any LOOP can be classified like `goto`, because IS GOTO. And I never would say, that loop by definition should have defined number of iterations. And your hope means you say, than `retry` keyword shouldn't be implemented, and it should be gone from languagen because it just reminds you `goto`?

Comment: Well, yes, everything is a `goto` in terms of the underlying machine code. We're talking about higher level code here though, in which specific restrictions and conventions are applied to get structure and better predictability into the code. That's why many high level languages eschew `goto` or severely restrict its freedom, to prevent arbitrary jumping around in the application. For that reason, because we're talking about high level logical structures, the separation between a "loop" and a "conditional" are important, even if they're all gotos behind the scenes.